# gtk_builder_new_from_file not present under Windows?

Tags: windows, gtk

I've been working for a couple of days with GTK3+ under Linux in C++ and I've used Glade to design my GUI. In my C++ code, I call `gtk_builder_new_from_file` instantiate the GUI.

Now I was trying to do the same under Windows. So, I downloaded the latest version of GTK+ (3.6.4, all-in-one 64-bit bundle). The problem is: I can't find the function `gtk_builder_new_from_file`. I've searched for it in all files too, but it seems not to be there. I've checked the documentation, and this function should be present since version 3.10.

So, why can't I find it? Is a Windows compatibility issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3.6.4 is a smaller version number than 3.10 so there does not seem to be any mystery here.

You should use `gtk_builder_add_from_file ()` instead if you can't find a newer Windows bundle.

Comment: so 10 is bigger than 6, uh? :/ Shame on me.